# Upload Image to Existing HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, kineticjs

I have a canvas with a set background image. You can then add text on top of the canvas and it is draggable. I want the user to be able to upload a draggable (and resizeable eventually) image to add to the canvas as well.

The code I have now is as follows:

```
var URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;

window.onload = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    input.addEventListener('change', handleFiles, false);
}

function handleFiles(e) {
    var ctx = memestage.getContext('2d');
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        img.add(bg);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 5, 5);    
    }
    img.src = url;

}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. More information can be provided on request. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the KineticJS code that draws the student’s name and photo on your id-card.

The student can drag their name and photo around the card.

The photo is not resizeable, but I have scaled the photo to fit in the photo area of your card.  If you change the card layout, you can easily adjust the width/height in the KineticJS Image Object.

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9jTtb/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.0-beta2.js"></script>
<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 472,
        height: 286
    });

    var layer=new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var preload=[];
    var images=[];
    preload.push("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/139992952/idcard.png");
    // I use a demo photo here
    // Of course in your live site, you would use URL.createObjectURL
    preload.push("http://macmcrae.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/bubblebobble.jpg");
    preloadImages(preload,init);

    function init(images){
        KImage("background",0,0,472,286,false,layer,images[0]);
        KImage("Photo",284,105,160,160,true,layer,images[1]);
        KText("Name",50,190,"Verdana",27,"black",true,layer,"Sam Student");
    }

    // image preloader
    function preloadImages(sources,callback){
        var images=[];
        var count=0;
        for(var i=0;i<preload.length;i++){
            images[i]=new Image();
            images[i].onload=function(){
                if(++count==preload.length){
                    callback(images);
                }
            }
            images[i].src=preload[i];
        }
    }

    // build the specified KineticJS Image and add it to the stage
    function KImage(id,x,y,width,height,isDraggable,layer,img){
        var kImg=new Kinetic.Image({
            image:img,
            id:id,
            x:x,
            y:y,
            width:width,
            height:height,
            draggable:isDraggable
        });
        layer.add(kImg);
        stage.draw();
    }

    // build the specified KineticJS Text and add it to the stage
    function KText(id,x,y,font,fontsize,color,isDraggable,layer,text){
        var kText=new Kinetic.Text({
            text:text,
            id:id,
            x:x,
            y:y,
            fontFamily:font,
            fontSize:fontsize,
            fill:color,
            draggable:isDraggable
        });
        layer.add(kText);
        stage.draw();
    };

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <img id="test"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Edited to answer OP’s additional requests]**

I looked at your code but couldn’t find any php upload script, so here is the general idea.

I assume you’ve already set up your configuration in php.ini, especially these:

- file_uploads = true;
- upload_max_filesize=2M; // or whatever max size you want the user to upload
- post_max_size=8M;

I assume you’ve already created a file folder to hold your uploaded files and given the webserver ownership (or adequate permissions).  The code below assumes the subdirectory is “uploads”.

Then the PHP code below will upload your user’s image and store it in the “uploads” directory using the same name as the user’s original file.

You still must modify this code for any bounds/error checking you feel is necessary.  Personally, I would do these as a minimum:

- $_FILES is not empty and it is an array
- $_FILES reports no errors occurred
- File name contains only these English characters [0-9][A-Z][.]
- File name is not more than250 characters
- File is not empty
- File is not larger than upload_max_size
- File has one of these extensions: .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png // or whatever you accept
- File does not already exist  // add logic to overwrite or bail out
- Catch routines on failures of the above tests

The php part would look like this:

```
<?php

var $uploadDirectory="uploads/";  // or whatever dir you set up
var $maxFileSize=1000000;         // or whatever max-size you allowed

// assuming 'file' is the name of your input-type-file tag

// oops, got an error
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){echo "Error occured: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>"; }

// get filepaths
var $tempfile=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
var $basefile=basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

// save the user's file
move_uploaded_file( $tempfile, $uploadDirectory . $basefile );

// do whatever other postback stuff you need to do

?>
```

And the HTML form would be something like this:

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000" />
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Still trying to implement this into my existing code but very helpful! Is there anyway that I can contact you for help if needed?

Comment: Glad I could help. If you have further questions I visit stackoverflow often!  Also, Check out this great site for examples of kineticjs: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-events-tutorials-introduction-with-kineticjs/

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing this into my current code. Basically, I'm able to add the image onto the canvas but then my create button no longer works. I think it has something to do with the preload function. Here is my complete code without trying to add this. Any help would be awesome. Thanks again!

Code: http://pastebin.com/BF2fmqdc

Comment: thank you, again! Great post. Thanks for taking the time to write that all out.

Comment: @Matthew Blackford: Chuckle...if you're listening, what did the poor double quote ever do to make you dislike it so much?  Good to meet you! :)

Comment: @markE I totally pressed the enter key by accident as I was writing my edit comment! I was planning to be much nicer to the old 99's :)